# VBA How to fix: "Property or method is not supported with this object" when cell securing in multiple sheets

Tags: vba

So bassicaly I want to secure a specific range within every sheet (same range always applies).

Code:

```html
Sub desecure()
  For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(x).Range("C7:P16").Protect Password:="30713"
  Next
End Sub
Sub secure()
  For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(x).Range("C7:P16").Protect Password:="30713"
  Next
End Sub
```

It always give the error stated in the question. Anyone knows how to fix this? (or a alternative)

Comment: I think that the `.Protect`method only applies to `Worksheet` objects. You have tried to use it on a `Range` object... and your two functions are identical BTW :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't protect a range - you set ranges to either "locked" or "unlocked" and then protect the whole sheet

To begin with, all cells are set to locked, but as the spreadsheet isn't protected this has no affect. In your case (assuming you want to be able to change other cells), you would need to unlock every other cell, lock the range you want to prevent changes in, and then protect the sheet. So

```
Sub secure()
dim ws as worksheet  'i change this line - typo
  For each ws in worksheets
    ws.cells.locked=false
    ws.Range("C7:P16").locked=true
    ws.Protect Password:="30713"
   next ws
 End Sub




 Sub Desecure
   dim ws as worksheet
   For each ws in worksheets
        ws.unprotect "30713"
    Next ws
   End Sub
```

Comment: I need to make sure that this command secures every sheet in my file.. don't know if he does that, anyhow,
When executing this after pasting your code, it says: 'Types don't match with eachother'

Comment: Another note: you have in the beginning a double code saying to;
End Sub

  Next
End sub

Comment: sorry typo - see edit in code, and yes it protects every worksheet in the workbook

Comment: Okay, the code is working, but it's now showing in excel the error that the sheet has been secured. is it possible to make that pop-up message in which you give in your password as we're used to it? (so without having to put the security completely down)

Comment: Note; when desecuring it, it shows again the message: 'types don't match'